Integral of odd periodic function is periodic
Let $f$ be a periodic function with period $\lambda$ and $f(-x) + f(x) = 0$ in the interval $\left[-\frac{\lambda}{2}, \frac{\lambda}{2}\right]$. Prove that
$$\int_a^{x} f(t) \, dt$$
is a periodic function with period $\lambda$.
How do I use the fact that $f(x)$ is odd?

The integral over $[-\lambda/2,\lambda/2]$ vanishes.

The odd parity of $f$ permits to conclude that its integral over the fundamental period vanishes $-$ as all odd functions do, when integrated over a symmetric interval, by the way $-$, i.e. $\int_{-\lambda/2}^{\lambda/2} f(t) \,\mathrm{d}t = 0$. If you want to rederive this result, you can do it by splitting the integral in two by separating the negative and positive parts of the domain of integration, before making the change of variable $t \mapsto -t$ in one of them.
We understand intuitively that this result can be translated to any interval whose length corresponds to the period of $f$. It can be shown by decomposing any real number $x$ as $x = -\frac{\lambda}{2} + k\lambda + x'$, where $k \in \Bbb{Z}$ and $x' \in [0,\lambda]$, which implies :
$$
\begin{align}
\int_x^{x+\lambda} f(t) \,\mathrm{d}t 
   &= \int_x^{-\lambda/2+(k+1)\lambda} f(t_1) \,\mathrm{d}t_1 + \int_{-\lambda/2+(k+1)\lambda}^{x+\lambda} f(t_2) \,\mathrm{d}t_2 \\
   &= \int_{x'}^{\lambda/2} f(t_1'+k\lambda) \,\mathrm{d}t_1' + \int_{-\lambda/2}^{x'} f(t_2'+(k+1)\lambda) \,\mathrm{d}t_2' \\
   &= \int_{-\lambda/2}^{\lambda/2} f(t) \,\mathrm{d}t \\
   &= 0
\end{align}
$$
where we took advantage of the changes of variables $t_1' = t_1 - k\lambda$ and $t_2' = t_2 -(k+1)\lambda$, as well as the periodicity of $f$. Now, we are ready to prove that the primitive of $f$ is also a $\lambda$-periodic function, as done below :
$$
\int_a^{x+\lambda} f(t) \,\mathrm{d}t 
   = \int_a^x f(t) \,\mathrm{d}t + \int_x^{x+\lambda} f(t) \,\mathrm{d}t
   = \int_a^x f(t) \,\mathrm{d}t
$$

Side note.
If $F(x) = \int_x^{x+\lambda} f(t) \,\mathrm{d}t$ is differentiable, then the end of the proof is even more straightforward, because $F'(x) = f(x+\lambda) - f(x) = 0$, meaning that $F$ is constant, hence $F(x) = F(-\lambda/2) = 0$.

So the main ingredient of our proof was $\int_0^{\lambda} f(t) , dt=0$

@rohit1729  Yes, it was, indeed.
